# How to select an element with jQuery using a variable in "contains" and remove the nearest el with class Foo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select an element using a variable in the selector to remove the nearest element with class `flag-container`. However, the element isn't removed when I trigger the function.

```js
function remove_div() {
    let comment_pk = 1
    $("div:contains('" + comment_pk + "')").closest('.flag-container').remove()
}

$('#trigger').click(function() {
    remove_div()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div hidden class="comment-pk">1</div>
<div class="drilled-hierarchy">
   <div class="flag-container">
      To be removed
   </div>
</div>


<button id="trigger"> Remove </button>
```

Comment: [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) goes *up* the hierarchy, you want `.next()` and `.find()` (a little more complicated as your "flag-container" is not directly related)

Comment: What **precisely** is your understanding of *nearest element*?

Comment: Aside from everything else, `:contains("1")` seems like it could **easily** match the wrong thing. Lots of elements will have the digit 1 *somewhere* in their text, presumably. (For instance, do you have one with `comment_pk = 10`?) You might consider putting the `comment_pk` on the `div` as a `data-*` attribute so you can use `div[data-comment-pk=1]` instead, which wouldn't match the one with `comment_pk = 10`.

Comment: although that was simplified from my own use case, your point is fair enough, thanks. Is there an alternative that searches for an entire match?

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].find(d=>d.textContent===String(comment_pk)).nextElementSibling.querySelector('.flag-container').remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your logic is that `closest()` travels **up** the DOM along **ancestor** elements. The `.flag-container` you're looking to target is instead a child of a sibling to the original `div`.

Therefore you can use `next()`* and `find()` instead:

```js
function remove_div() {
  let comment_pk = 1
  $("div:contains('" + comment_pk + "')").next('.drilled-hierarchy').find('.flag-container').remove()
}

$('#trigger').click(function() {
  remove_div()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div hidden class="comment-pk">1</div>
<div class="drilled-hierarchy">
  <div class="flag-container">
    To be removed
  </div>
</div>


<button id="trigger">Remove</button>
```

*using a selector string argument in the `next()` call is optional in this case, but saves unexpected bugs later. `siblings()` may also be appropriate depending on your exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS, will only find exact matches:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')]
  .find(d=>d.textContent===String(comment_pk))
  .nextElementSibling
  .querySelector('.flag-container')
  .remove();
```